# Custom URL with form

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, url, redirect, uri

I am working on codeigniter, and have a search bar that I want to map to a search class in a controller. The URL currently is `search/searchterm`. I want to build out a form that adheres to this and would esentially just take whatever is in the form and pass it to the URL. I've tried just doing a javascript relocation onsubmit like this:

```
document.location.href= "<?= base_url() ?>" + document.forms["searchbox"]["search"].value
```

but it doesn't seem to work. What do you guys recommend as the best for something like this? I'm sure tons of people require something similar to what I want in their projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another sample. It is a valid xhtml document and searches in google whatever you type in the search box. It works in FF10, IE8, Chrome 17 and Opera 11.61.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            var form = document.getElementById("form1");
            form.onsubmit = function(){
                var searchText = document.getElementById("searchText");
                window.location = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchText.value;
                return false;
            };          
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
        <div>
            <label for="searchText">Search:</label>
            <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" />
            <input type="submit" value="Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

That would work if it was not inside a form, to do that inside a form you need to set the onsubmit event to set the appropriate action to the form.

Here is a simple working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function foo() {
            document.forms["searchbox"].action= window.location.href+"/" + document.forms["searchbox"]["search"].value; 
            return true; 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form  id="searchbox" onsubmit="foo()" > 
        <input type="text" id="search" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```